# Fail to create a Docker with customized, up-to-date Firefox and sound

Tags: docker, ubuntu, firefox, debian, dockerfile

I'm trying to create a debian/ubuntu based Docker container, with an up-to-date Firefox for me and my colleagues, with some minor adjustments (i.e. add-ons and start page).

I'd want to create the image, customise Firefox, commit the changes and distribute the image. I'm also looking for a simple way to update Firefox and not remove any customisation - this is a problem for future me.

**On a host Kubuntu 19.04 (VBox) with Docker Version 18.09.7**

I've tried numerous approaches to get a current Firefox version working - WITH SOUND. Here's my results:

- - debian:stable-slim w/ firefox-esr doesn't work (no errors, no play)
- - debian:stable-slim w/ firefox (binary) doesn't work (errors)
- - debian:stable-slim w/ firefox-beta (binary) doesn't work (errors)
- - debian:stable-slim w/ firefox-dev (binary) doesn't work (errors)
- - debian:stable-slim w/ firefox-nightly (binary) doesn't work (errors)
- **- debian:testing-slim w/ firefox-esr WORKS**
- - debian:testing-slim w/ firefox (binary) doesn't work (errors)
- - debian:testing-slim w/ firefox-beta (binary) doesn't work (errors)
- - debian:testing-slim w/ firefox-dev (binary) doesn't work (errors)
- - debian:testing-slim w/ firefox-nightly (binary) doesn't work (errors)
- - debian:sid-slim w/ firefox doesn't (no errors, no play)
- - debian:sid-slim w/ firefox (binary) doesn't work (errors)
- - debian:sid-slim w/ firefox-beta (binary) doesn't work (errors)
- - debian:sid-slim w/ firefox-dev (binary) doesn't work (errors)
- - debian:sid-slim w/ firefox-nightly (binary) doesn't work (errors)
- - ubuntu:latest w/ firefox doesnt' work (errors)
- - ubuntu:latest w/ firefox (binary) doesn't work (errors)
- - ubuntu:latest w/ firefox-beta (binary) doesn't work (errors)
- - ubuntu:latest w/ firefox-dev (binary) doesn't work (errors)
- - ubuntu:latest w/ firefox-nightly (binary) doesn't work (errors)
- - ubuntu:rolling w/ firefox doesn't work (errors)
- - ubuntu:rolling w/ firefox (binary) doesn't work (errors)
- - ubuntu:rolling w/ firefox-beta (binary) doesn't work (errors)
- - ubuntu:rolling w/ firefox-dev (binary) doesn't work (errors)
- - ubuntu:rolling w/ firefox-nightly (binary) doesn't work (errors)

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND teletype
RUN apt update && apt install -y firefox breeze ubuntu-restricted-extras
COPY firefox /opt/firefox
COPY firefox-beta /opt/firefox-beta
COPY firefox-dev /opt/firefox-dev
COPY firefox-nightly /opt/firefox-nightly
RUN useradd -m -G audio,video user
USER user
CMD ["/usr/bin/firefox"]
```

For the different distributions the `FROM` changes of course, the `ubuntu-restricted-extras` is only for Ubuntu and `apt install firefox` changes to `apt install firefox-esr` for Debian stable and testing.

Docker run:

```
docker run -v ~/Downloads:/home/user/Downloads -e DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix --shm-size 2G --device /dev/dri --device /dev/snd -it <image> bash
```

Anytime the list above mentions `(error)`, it's a the following:

```
[Child 319, MediaDecoderStateMachine #1] WARNING: 7f2f106f4390 OpenCubeb() failed to init cubeb: file /builds/worker/workspace/build/src/dom/media/AudioStream.cpp, line 305
[Child 319, MediaDecoderStateMachine #1] WARNING: Decoder=7f2f10603400 [OnMediaSinkAudioError]: file /builds/worker/workspace/build/src/dom/media/MediaDecoderStateMachine.cpp, line 3641
[Child 319, MediaDecoderStateMachine #1] WARNING: Decoder=7f2f10603400 Decode error: NS_ERROR_DOM_MEDIA_MEDIASINK_ERR (0x806e000b) - OnMediaSinkAudioError: file /builds/worker/workspace/build/src/dom/media/MediaDecoderStateMachine.cpp, line 3309
```

Firefox-ESR works on Debian:testing-slim, but ESR a tad too outdated for me.I'd rather not run a TCP pulseaudio server on my host for the sound to work.

How do I get a recent version of Firefox to work with sound on a Debian based Docker?

Comment: When you say "interactive desktop application" and "with sound", you're hitting two areas where it's very hard to use Docker.  A virtual machine would be a better fit.

Comment: thanks for the comment. This shouldn't be much of an issue though. Jessie Frazelle showed exactly this off in 2015 (https://blog.jessfraz.com/post/docker-containers-on-the-desktop/) and I have it working for one setup - it's just being a little stubborn I'd say.

Comment: The 11-line `docker run` command there to run Chrome?  It is still the only way to do this, and I'd continue to describe this (four years later) much more as "cool hack" more than "production-ready best practice".

Comment: huh. does chrome vs. firefox make this much of a difference? Thanks for your insight.